# how to change the color of <mat-dialog-title>

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I try to do this, but it doesn't work

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title color="primary">{{ title }}</h1>
```

I need to change the color of the {{ title }}, but this method dint work.. do you have a solution???

Comment: Please provide the important code parts of your angular component. You are also not using a binding here. And you should consider to bind to `[ngStyle]="{ 'color': primary }"`.

Answer (score 1):

thank you it work when i add

```
.mat-dialog-title {
    color: mat-color($primary);
}
```

in scss file